# How to insert Image URLs in MySql using Scala and Liftweb

Tags: mysql, scala, lift

i want to insert image URLs in to MySql Database using scala and Liftweb

i am not good at database please suggest me

Best Regards
GSY

Comment: an URL can be treated just like a normal string. An example of a lift application that uses persistence can be seen here: http://demo.liftweb.net/simple/index

Comment: Do you want to insert URLs or images?